# Sorting by rows

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

Is there any way for one to mimic with a macro the Sort command in Excel with the following example?

I have 60 rows and 53 columns of data.  Upon using the sort command I was indeed able to get the results I wanted but believe if I could have a macro, it would save me so much time.  You can see the before and after images to have a visual of what I have been trying to accomplish.

[[image: Before Sort]]

[[image: After Sort]]

e.g.

```
SORT LEFT TO RIGHT

SORT BY [ROW 2] | SORT ON [VALUES] | ORDER [SMALLEST TO LARGEST]
SORT BY [ROW 3] | SORT ON [VALUES] | ORDER [SMALLEST TO LARGEST]
...
...
SORT BY [ROW 59] | SORT ON [VALUES] | ORDER [SMALLEST TO LARGEST]
SORT BY [ROW 60] | SORT ON [VALUES] | ORDER [SMALLEST TO LARGEST]
```

UPDATE: I ran the macro recorder to see what it would look like, here is the shortened code from row 2 to row 61.

```
Sub Macro3()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:BB2") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B3:BB3") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B4:BB4") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B5:BB5") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ...MORE ROWS HERE IN THE PATTERN AS SHOWN
    ...MORE ROWS HERE IN THE PATTERN AS SHOWN
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B57:BB57" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B58:BB58" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B59:BB59" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B60:BB60" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B61:BB61" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B1:BB63")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Is there anyway to make this more concise?

Comment: In short, you want to sort by rows instead of by columns? Did I misunderstand?

Comment: I believe what I am looking to do is sort by rows.  The pictures should show pretty good what I am talking about.  I may not be explaining it very well.

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet if possible?

Comment: See the updated code I posted, this is from the Macro Recorder.  Is there a way to shorten this down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort by rows in Excel directly, no VBA needed:

```
Data->Sort->Options...->Sort left to right
```

I you want to sort from vba, specify Rows as criteria field:

```
Sub SortByRows()
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Sort Key1:=.Rows(1), Key2:=.Rows(2), Key3:=.Rows(3)
    End With
End Sub
```

You are limited in the number of criteria, though. Since you need more criteria fields, it is trickier:

```
Sub SortByRows()
    With ActiveSheet
        Set target = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, .UsedRange.Columns.Count))
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SetRange target
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .Header = xlNo

        For Each r In target.Rows
           .SortFields.Add r
        Next
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I just posted something I copied from the Macro Recorder which is uses the method you posted.  I used the method you mentioned originally to create the goal I am wanting to reach.  I just dont want to have to each time add 60 lines in the sort command and change each sort option to the next row.

Comment: Ok, one moment plz ;)

Comment: @Born2Discover please see the added last piece of code.

Comment: This is incredibly close to what I was looking for but though headers are declared "which I have headers in row A" it doesn't do it correctly.  If I delete Row A and run the macro it does exactly as the image above shows.  Any way around this?  I will give best answer to you for sure by the way.

Comment: @Born2Discover the new version of the code should do it. Basically the difficuly was in automatically identify the target range, since the data in your worksheet is sparse and spread somehow randomly. We could hardcode the target range but it would make the macros not adaptive. Hopefully this version should do.

Comment: This is indeed a solution but since it cannot keep the headers in place, I believe the only way around this is to just keep using that really long macro created by the recorder.  Thanks to everyone for your help.  Best answer awarded to A.S.H.